# PHP MYSQL event sheduler like Musicteacherhelper.com

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, fullcalendar, recurring-events

I have search over php mysql recurring events but didnt find anything exactly like i want.

I want to develop event sheduler in php mysql in which user add reccuring events based on daily,weekly,montly,yearly patterns using html form which is stored in mysql using php.

Like for example

user will enter start date,end date, what time event will happen(like 4:30pm) and duration of the event(like 2 hrs so it will make 430pm to 630pm event) with repeating patterns.For example event will repeat after 3 days , on monday and wednesday every week or after every two weeks, every 10th day of month or every 10th day after two months, on specific date every year or without any repeating patterns just add event for any specific date .

This information will be taken from user using html form and will be stored in mysql database and than it needs to display user upcoming events(e.g consider today is 13th july 2013 if recurring event is sheduled for 15th july 2013 it will consider as upcoming events) or events in the past(e.g consider today is 13th july 2013 if event is sheduled for 10th july 2013 it will be consider as past event) using php in two different ways using html table and arshaw full calendar.

I need help how i store event information in mysql database and than pull it using php and display upcoming or past events in html table and also be to integrate it arshaw full calendar.

This sort of stuff is already working in musicteacherhelper.com which also used php and mysql for implementing so i need to know is there any open source code available to implement this functionality.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Talha

Answer (score 0):

use industry standard `RRULE` to store the informaton and some metadata of event in some mysql table for search purpose (example : date range)

```
http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/rrule.html
demo : http://jkbr.github.io/rrule/
```

there are js and php libraries available for the same.